# Volley.newRequestQueue is causing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, caching, out-of-memory, android-volley

I am using Volley to set an image url. My code is crashing at:

```
mrq=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Log cat says that the exemption is at: `com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes`

If I comment the code out the program does not crash.

I have tried restarting my phone a couple times because in my research I found that has worked for some with this problem.

Why is creating a RequestQueue using so much memory?

How can I prevent the OutOfMemoryError from happening?

Do I need to empty the cache?

Thank you for your help and taking the time to read this.

Comment: Are you initiating mrq i.e. RequestQueue in activity?

Comment: I am.      `private RequestQueue mrq;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you initialize your RequestQueue? I suspect that you are creating RequestQueues for each activity.So initiate it in your **Application** class as

```
    public class ApplicationController extends Application {
        private static ApplicationController sInstance;
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

        @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

 public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }



        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
                // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
                // created when it is accessed for the first time
                if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                }

                return mRequestQueue;
            }


    //your code


    }
```

And getRequest queue from your activity as

```
mrq = ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
```

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. I can see how that could cause a problem. I have implemented the function that you suggest and I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Please clear cache and Re-run app Or simply try to reinstall the app and Did you add request to queue as mrq.add(req);

Comment: @user3594241 Are you setting image using ImageLoader

Comment: Yes, I am using ImageLoader.

Comment: @lock Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

A key concept is that the RequestQueue must be instantiated with the Application context, not an Activity context. This ensures that the RequestQueue will last for the lifetime of your app, instead of being recreated every time the activity is recreated